# cxf-codegen-plugin additional WSDL xsd:schema import?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I have a WSDL file for a WebService that I don't control that is missing some schema imports, which leads to JAX-WS returning me DOM Objects, while I want JAXB Objects.

When adding the schema import to WSDL manually, I do get JAXB objects (wrapped in `JAXBElements`, due to xsd any but that is another issue), but I would prefer not updating WSDL in case of future external updates to it.

Currently the code is generated using `cxf-codegen-plugin` (see below).

Is it possible to add an additional `<xsd:import />` to the WSDL?

I tried to find information on whether this is possible via a ["JAX-WS Binding File"](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html#Mavencxfcodegenplugin(WSDLtoJava)-Example1:PassinginaJAX-WSBindingfile), but did not (yet?) really find info on it in general.

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <wsdlOptions>
                <wsdlOption>
                  <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/ExternalService.wsdl</wsdl>
                </wsdlOption>
              </wsdlOptions>
              <sourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/gen/java</sourceRoot>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

```xml
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0" schemaLocation="pstc_spmlv2_core.xsd"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0:search" schemaLocation="pstc_spmlv2_search.xsd"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="urn:vnd:...:1.0:spmlCapabilityData" schemaLocation="vnd_..._spmlv2_capabilitydata.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
```